# How to fix a MultiValueDictKeyError

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am trying to get the time spent on each page in a Django project using Javascript. I keep getting an error so I am trying to fix it

the error:

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /backendurl/
'timeSpent'
```

Highlighted line of error in views.py:

```
    timeSpent = request.POST['timeSpent']
```

Here is the javascript in template:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var startDate = new Date();

  $(window).unload(function() {
      var endDate = new Date();
      $.ajax({
        type: POST,
        url: "backendurl", // be mindful of url names
        data: {
          'timeSpent': endDate - startDate || 'none' // defaults to a string
        },
        success: function(response) {

          // unpack response:
          status = response.status

        }
      })
</script>
```

Here is the views.py:

```
def my_view_function(request):
    timeSpent = request.POST['timeSpent']
    response = json.dumps({
        'timeSpent' : timeSpent,
    })
    return HttpResponse(response)
```

Here is the url.py

```
    path('backendurl/', views.my_view_function, name='backendurl'),
```

Comment: idk the *js* side, but, the issue is, in your POST payload, the key named **`timeSpent`** is not present and you are trying to access the same key in the Django.

Answer (score 0):

In most probability, the key **`'timeSpent'`** is not present in **`request.POST`**.

To get the key's value from **`request.POST`** dict you need to use the **MultiValuedDict's get method**.

You can also put a default to know that you have not got the key in your request, -1 in this case below.

```
timeSpent = request.POST.get('timeSpent', -1)
```

Comment: there is progress now it is showing not error but it is only showing `{"timeSpent": -1}`

Comment: Yeah, that's to avoid the error only, its -1 because you are not getting `'timeSpent'` from **`request.POST`**.